# php base_convert but with own character-table

Tags: php

i want generate serial numbers for numbers maybe up to  99 999, and make them as short as possible. I intend to use base_convert($nr,10,32), and str_pad to padd left side with zeroes for smaller numbers.

```
base_convert('VVVV', 32, 10); // can provide numbering up to: 1 048 575
```

to avoid problematic characters (0/O, I/1), i then add string replacement in array

```
['O'=>'W', 'I'=>'X', '1'=>'Y', '0'=>'Z']
```

- That above array is the reason i use base32, remaining leters WXYZ will be used for replacment of character that may be misread.

My question, is there some other nicer or better way, to get short serial by using own array of characters for custom base convert? (for example i may also add $,#,!,@,&, and ommit the problematic 0,O,1,I characters). If someone has the code at hand, i'd be happy to check it out.

Comment: It sounds like you generally have something [like this](https://3v4l.org/9dnRj), possibly with some better input testing? Your method is pretty sound to me. My one theoretical worry would be about someone giving you unexpected values, and how it maps through this process, but I think you could RegEx scan for your supported characters before passing through.

Comment: thanks @ChrisHaas, yes at moment i have something like that, just also with strtoupper to make all letters uppercase to make it all look better together. I desided to not add special characters like mentioned in the original question (#,$,@,..) so im sticking with this solution